# How do I position html intense widget without interfering with search optimization

Tags: php, javascript

I have a widget that is comprised of quite a few divs. I then use javascript to bring the widget to life and do what it is supposed to do.

It is positioned on the page above the main content.

The client feels having all the widget html above the keyword rich content is bad for rankings, yet visually this is how we want the page set up.

What are some options here to keep the widget positioned as we want, yet not clutter up the top of the page as it is crawled?

current setup:

-javascript file is called in head
-widget html, which is several divs, text, images, etc.
-other page content divs

Comment: You shouldn't get that much concerned about where on your page your content is located. If you mangle the page and even very few users don't share/link it because it doesn't work anymore for them that would have shared it otherwise, your impact on search results is far more dramatic than any source-sequence-seo placebo.

Answer (score 0):

You could include the widget at the bottom of the page, then use css to position it at the top.  Make sure your main content has a top-margin equivalent to the size of the widget. As mentioned in your comment, you'd also need to position the widget sufficiently far down the page to avoid the header content.  This relies on your header and widget having specified heights.  Your html would be something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">The header</div>
    <div class="main-content">The main content</div>
    <div class="widget">widget</div>
</body>
```

Then your css could be something like this:

```
.header, .main-content, .widget {
    height: 40px;
}

.header {
    background-color: red;
}

.main-content {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 40px; /* height of widget */
}

.widget {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px; /* height of header */
}
```

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/W3RzU/

As bardiir pointed out, putting the widget code in the correct place would be much simpler and would have minimal (if any) impact on seo.

Comment: Actually there is more information above the widget, so I actually need css for header content, then the widget, then main content. I have every thing working pretty close but positioning the widget absolutely with a top of 0 puts it over the header and some top of the page content.